# Can I promote my new website on my current website without a penalty from Google?

Tags: seo, google, advertising, penalty

On my current website, can I promote a link for my new website which has completely different content?

For example, I want to add this type of promotion on the front page, profile pages, post pages, and tag pages:

[image]

Will Google penalize my current website or not?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can promote your own websites on other websites you own. Google would never penalize you for this. In fact, big sites do this all the time when they have a network of sites that go over various categories. For example, [thebump.com](https://www.thebump.com/) has this promotion in their footer on all pages and at all times:

[image]

This would only become a concern if you started to create what is referred to as a PBN (private blog network). This would be a big network of sites that you own that link to each other in the hopes of improving your backlink profile.

Comment: for that link i can use nofollow for google not read like PBN?

Comment: Yeah, you can certainly do that to be extra safe.

Answer (score 0):

Why should he do so?

It is a normal behaviour, so there woud be no penalty.

If you want to improve your other website link profile, try these:

1. get links from domains hosted on IP addresses other it’s own (host them on separate servers if possible)
2. get links from a textual context
3. do not link just to homepage
4. choose a good link text
5. try link text relevant and similar to linked page’s title and url (slug)

Answer (score 0):

Google will not penalise your websites since the link is natural and that you are not breaking the [official Google Webmaster Guidelines](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35769?hl=en).